# Multiple Default Buttons in a User Control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, defaultbutton

I have a user control that is comprised of 3 textboxes, 3 buttons and a gridview.  I can set the defaultbutton property of the form, but that would only affect one button.

Each textbox/button combo should have a behavior that when the textbox has focus, pressing Enter should fire its associated button.

To further complicate the issue, this is being used inside a Master Page implementation.

Is there any way to do this?  As far as I can tell, .NET will only allow one default button - it doesn't provide to explicitly associate textboxes and buttons.

I welcome your insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here one way:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" DefaultButton="Button1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" DefaultButton="Button2" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" DefaultButton="Button3" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a separate User Control for each TextBox/Button set.  That way each Textbox will fire it's associated Button.

Comment: I see what you mean, but to me that overcomplicates the page.  I might as well just have the users just click the associated button.  I have them doing that now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the default button and handle the textbox's onKeyPress event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sweet solution by usage of an **Attached Property**:
http://neilmosafi.blogspot.com/2007/04/default-buttons-in-wpf-and-multiple.html

Just create a class with the attached property code of the article and add it to controls, which encapsulate each TextBox and Button pair.

Example: `<StackPanel ... local:AccessKeyScoper.IsAccessKeyScope="True"> <TextBox ... /> <Button ... /> </StackPanel>`

Note:
If you add the file with the Dependency Property to a subdirectory, you need to use an other namespace definition instead of `local:`.